# IntelliJ deployment on tomcat not working with no error

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, jakarta-ee, intellij-idea

I am fairly new to IntelliJ. I am trying to deploy a simple application(Spring) with a minimal configuration classes from a book and a single home controller.

The problem is that it blocks here:

```
INFO: Server startup in 90 ms
Connected to server
[2015-03-10 01:26:17,221] Artifact Projefic:war exploded: Artifact is being deployed, please wait...
[2015-03-10 01:26:18,312] Artifact Projefic:war exploded: Artifact is deployed successfully
[2015-03-10 01:26:18,313] Artifact Projefic:war exploded: Deploy took 1,092 milliseconds
Mar 10, 2015 2:26:27 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory E:\Work\Tools\apache-tomcat-7.0.47-projefic\webapps\manager
```

And there is no error and I can't make it to work. I tried to delete the `manager` folder from `webapps` but it's not working either.

These are my configurations:
[image]

[image]

[image]

I can provide the code from the classes but the problem shouldn't be from there..

Comment: So you're saying, you don't see the line `Server startup in xxx ms` at the end and you are not able to go to `localhost:8080` and see the Tomcat start page? I'm not familiar with IntelliJ, but I'd recommend trying to start the Tomcat from the command line and see if it behaves differently.

Comment: Sorry for the late response but I was busy and couldn't find time to get back to this problem. Your suggestion helped me thanks! There was a problem with the tomcat in the first place. Had some errors on the startup..